# pgfplotstable: trouble reading data from file with leading zero

Tags: pgfplotstable, pgfmath

when i create a table within the process of LaTeX, i am able to access the items, for example in a loop. If i read a table from a file with  "\pgfplotstableread" then it refuses to read in values with an index bigger than 6 and a trailing 0. It gives the message:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Digit `8' invalid for base 8 (in '08').
```

But how can i read values with a leading zero, or, how can i change the base to 10? The code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
  create on use/One/.style={create col/set list={01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10}},
  create on use/Two/.style={create col/set list={11,45,63,7,30,63,18,22,78,10}}
  }
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={One, Two}]{10}\NewTableT

% Reading the table
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{One}\of\NewTableT
\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{Two}\of\NewTableT

%Running:
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}{
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{One}\of{\NewTableT}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Monat}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\x}{Two}\of{\NewTableT}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Tag}{\pgfplotsretval}
  {\x} Day: {\Tag} and  Month: {\Monat}\\
}

\line(1,0){200}

% data in table zeitentabelle.dat:
%% Monat Tag Anfang Ende
%% 01 01 0 0
%% 01 02 0 0
%% 01 03 0 0
%% 01 04 0 0
%% 01 05 0 0
%% 01 06 0 0
%% 01 07 7 16
%% 01 08 7 17
%% 01 09 6 17
%% 01 10 0 0
%% 01 11 0 0

% Reading the table
\pgfplotstableread{zeitentabelle.dat}\NewTable
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{Monat}\of\NewTable
\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{Tag}\of\NewTable
\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{Anfang}\of\NewTable
\pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{Ende}\of\NewTable

%Not Running for numbers bigger than "08":
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}{
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{Monat}\of{\NewTable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Monat}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\x}{Tag}\of{\NewTable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Tag}{\pgfplotsretval}
  {\x} Day: {\Tag} and  Month: {\Monat}\\
}

\end{document}
```

And the error messsage:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Digit `8' invalid for base 8 (in '08').
```

Comment: I get the error in texlive 2014, but in 2015 and miktex it is gone.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike, i´ve checked texlive (tex --version) and it seems that it is 2013. Have to find out how to update it on opensuse...